# Stretch div to div which has fixed width

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have 2 divs inline. One of which has fixed width. I want div to fill in all the space until the second div when the window adjusts. To clarify the situation, take a look at picture below:

[image]

After resizing window I need to get next layout:

[image]

How to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take advantage of `display:table-cell`.

**[Demo](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/vFfbq)**